# Why Fetch post request It's not returning headers but curl -XPOST yes

Tags: javascript, curl, fetch-api

I'm doing authentication and the endpoint is working when I do an `XPOST` request

The response returns the headers with the Bearer token.

`curl -XPOST -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{ "user": { "email": "test@email.com", "password": "mypassword" } }' http://localhost:3000/login`

The response shows the headers

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 0
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Download-Options: noopen
X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies: none
Referrer-Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Vary: Accept, Origin
Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiI2NjhjMGQ0Ni01MTRlLTQ5YzQtODYxNy01OTAwYzBhN2UwYjIiLCJzY3AiOiJ1c2VyIiwiYXVkIjpudWxsLCJpYXQiOjE2NjgyMDY0MzIsImV4cCI6MTY3MDc5ODQzMiwianRpIjoiYWVlYzdiZTQtZGMwMC00NTcwLWE1NmMtMjIxNDI5Mjg2OTI5In0.JbqtDysqaDSIcGAtqPPy7sIYKupDHPopzvbWLuNji5s
ETag: W/"d7798a9ef354a1fcb018db70449e0f38"

...

{"message":"Logged in successfully"}
```

But when I use fetch

```
const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/login`, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ user: { email:"test@email.com", password: "mypassword" } }),
  });
  const data = await response.json();
  console.log(data);
```

Shows only `{"message":"Logged in successfully"}`

I tried to inspect the `response.headers()` and are empty

Ideas, why fetch, is not returning the headers?
The backend is local ruby rails server

Comment: `response.headers` is NOT a function - also if this is a CORS request, only some [CORS-safelisted headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/CORS-safelisted_response_header) are exposed by default

Comment: Yes I can access headers

Comment: No, I can use `response. heders` but is empty when I use fetch.

Comment: for a start, you should be using `response.headers` - try adding `console.log(response.headers)` to your code and report what is output - secondly, check the browser developer tools to see what headers the browser is receiving